# What happens behind the scenes when you move a web app from one app service Plan to another

Tags: azure, azure-app-service-plans

We have been moving some Azure web apps from one app service plan to another.
I am just wondering what happens behind the scenes.

It works great but how does all the code etc get shipped to the new VMs under the hood?

Comment: If I understand correctly, you're asking for internal implementation of a service feature. That really wouldn't fit here, as it's only going to get you speculation. This is the "magic" of PaaS - things are simply taken care of for you. If the details aren't officially documented, then really there's nothing that can be said here...

Comment: You just change the service plan, not the VM. I've swapped betweeen different service plans - it's pretty straightforward. By the way, this is more of a question for the Azure team, don't you think?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because - it's a sales related question that is best answered by the Azure team, to be honest.

Comment: @DavidMakogon thanks for your answer. This question was to just get a better understanding of what goes on behind the scenes but I suppose Microsoft doesn't need us to know that with PaaS. code4Life I know you just change the ASP but as the new ASP uses different wrkr pools (we are using an ASE) then the code that was on the VM instances in the 1st wrkr pool that the 1st ASP was using then surely the code must get shipped to the wrkr pool that the 2nd ASP uses. Also, how is this sales related, it is a valid question and I tagged it with Azure tag so the Azure team at Microsoft could comment.

Comment: The code is stored in Azure Storage behind the scenes so there is nothing to move actually. I *speculate* they just set it up on new instances from a pool, apply config, re-route traffic and that's it.